# Насколько важно не потерять инкапсуляцию на уровне пакета?

Tags: java, ооп

Я пишу проект на java. Создавал все классы в одном пакете и в один момент их количество достигло 20. И это только те, которые отвечают за GUI. тогда я решил что надо разбить их по пакетам :) Многие из этих классов - это мои наследники классов Swing - MyScroll, MyButton и т.д. Всего около 10 таких классов. Их используют другие 10 классы, занимающиеся непосредственно построением GUI. Сейчас эти 10, которые являются наследниками классов Swing у меня не являются публичными. А если я их вынесу в отдельный пакет их придется сделать публичными. Очень интересно стоит ли их выносить и какие вообще могут быть рекомендации по этой теме? Ведь с одной стороны, проект будет лучше структурирован, с другой стороны я  потеряю инкапсуляцию на уровне пакета, правильно? Гуглил - не нашел. В книгах тоже - просто сухой текст насчет того что такое пакеты, как их создавать и как импортировать. А хотелось бы поглубже разобраться.

Answer (score 3):

20 классов в пакете — это в целом не очень много. К примеру, в Java-8 в пакете `java.util` 116 файлов .java (не считая подпакетов). Поэтому пока повода для беспокойства нет.

Не забывайте про другой способ организации исходников: можно использовать вложенные классы. Если, например, в вашем пакете `com.example` есть классы, рисующие интерфейс `MyButton`, `MyLabel` и есть некий главный класс типа `MyWindow` или `MyFrame`, часто разумно вспомогательные классы разместить внутри:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private static class MyButton extends JButton { ... }
    private static class MyLabel extends JLabel { ... }
    ...
}
```

Такой код проще читать: понятно, что `MyButton` и `MyLabel` используются только `MyFrame`. Конечно, тут тоже надо знать меру: если вложенных классов много, размер исходника вырастет до некомфортных размеров.

Альтернативный подход — использовать модульную систему типа OSGi, где каждый jar — это отдельный модуль или плагин, который может определить (в файле MANIFEST.MF) экспортируемые и неэкспортируемые пакеты. Тогда вы можете иметь `com.example`, содержащий публичные классы, и, например, `com.example.internal`, содержащий детали реализации. Классы из `internal` будут тоже объявлены публичными, но плагин не будет экспортировать этот пакет, поэтому из других плагинов в OSGi-приложении он не будет доступен.

Что-то подобное нам предложит Java-9 и проект Jigsaw: там можно будет создать файлик `module-info.java` и написать, какие пакеты видны за пределами данного модуля.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, не очень понятна структура проекта и по этому сложно прямо вот так дать какую-то рекомендацию. Логично предположить, что кто-то из классов, которые отвечают за построение GUI, должен быть виден наружу, просто для того, чтобы запустить отрисовку. Можно например вынести их в отдельный пакет и сделать package private, а затем, например, создать там же какой-нибудь public class GUIBuilder с методом build(), который будет запускать всю процедуру. Лично я выношу классы в отдельный пакет для группировки функционала